# Flutter Desktop User activity outside application

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, time-tracking, user-activity

I am trying to build time tracker app in flutter desktop. I can take screenshots using screen_capture package. But how I can detect how active user was even if the application is in background.
Please let me know how this could be achieved.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter does not include any functionality to monitor other applications. You would need to implement it separately for each platform you support, using [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Comment: Thank you for ansering. Can you give me any tutorial how I can do it?

Comment: @CeeJay The page I linked to has a tutorial for implementing a platform channel.